# Forcing an eni change when changing subnets in a rds subnet group

Tags: amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

I'm looking at changing the subnets that our RDS instances are currently in.

The subnet group currently has `/20` for both a & c zones. I've created new `/22` subnets for a & c and associated them for the subnet group, removing the old ones.

I've been running `dig` on the rds dns name and the IP that is being returned is still from one of the old `/20` subnets.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to resolve this so I can remove the old eni's and subnets.

I've tried toggling the "multi-az" on/off as well as forcefully removing the old (and in use) eni (won't detach).

Short of snapshotting the database and restoring using a new subnet group (i.e. downtime) is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured it out by now, but you have to reboot the RDS. It will force the update. However you still have a small downtime.

Alternatively, a more elegant approach is to create a read replica (in a new subnet group, with the new subnets added to it), add the new endpoint to your db driver's server list & promote it to master. Which, if your db driver supports it, can be without downtime from app standpoint(using for e.g. silent failover or other similar mechanisms).